# Set current project to default-6c6f02 (in build file:/home/user_name/Videos/

Tags: scala, sbt

what does it mean when running sbt command in command line in scala .
Set current project to default-6c6f02 (in build file:/home/user_name/Videos/

what should i set after this statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens if you call `sbt` command in the folder where you don't have built. sbt`or project/Build.scala`, as i understand in your case it's `/home/user_name/Videos/`. And because you dont' have any build configuration in the current folder, sbt creates a default one. You can fix this easily, just add small `build.sbt` file with:

```
name := "project name"

version := "0.1"
```

Please notice the blank line between settings, in `build.sbt` this is necessary

Comment: @Alexlv how to run existing project in eclipse. please explain. i am beggner. Please?

Comment: @user3408937 Sorry i'm not an eclipse user, but as i remember there should be a green button `RunAs -> Scala Application`

Comment: i combile and run hello world application. but when i run Existing project i have a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349450/error-while-running-openie-using-scala

Comment: @4lex1v I have exactly the same problem; however, I cannot understand what do you mean by add a file?
Do you mean, in the same directory that I have my batch file, I should add a build.sbt file containing the commands that you mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to set anything, sbt is telling you it has set the current project to this.

Comment: how to compile and run exising project?

Comment: @Alexey Yes. It is just info: `[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/home/user/myproject/)`