# Error while running openIE using scala

Tags: java, scala

i am running openIE in scala. while running sbt run i got error. can any body explain? 
    Set current project to openie (in build file:/home/user_name/Videos/openie-master/)

```
[info] Running edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIECli 
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MODULE$

[error]     at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.scalaPropOrNone(Properties.scala:65)

[error]     at scala.util.Properties$.scalaPropOrNone(Properties.scala:16)

[error]     at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.$init$(Properties.scala:77)

[error]     at scala.util.Properties$.<init>(Properties.scala:16)

[error]     at scala.util.Properties$.<clinit>(Properties.scala)

[error]     at scala.compat.Platform$.<init>(Platform.scala:112)

[error]     at scala.compat.Platform$.<clinit>(Platform.scala)
[error]     at scala.App$class.$init$(App.scala:42)
[error]     at edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIECli$.<init>(OpenIECli.scala:29)
[error]     at edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIECli$.<clinit>(OpenIECli.scala)
[error]     at edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIECli.main(OpenIECli.scala)
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of Scala that was used to compile openIE?

Comment: @GáborBakos not sure please guide me ? i am beggner in scala. trying to implement openIE. please

Comment: According to the sbt file (https://github.com/knowitall/openie/blob/v4.1/build.sbt) it uses 2.10. What is your Scala version? Are you using sbt or Maven? Something else? (Probably this option still works if you want to be sure about Scala version: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7532)